# Having trouble accessing value of array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access array values by key ( `echo $data['code']`), or casting as object, and I'm being hit with
`Uncaught Exception: Notice: Undefined index: code`.
For debugging purposes, I've tried to access them by doing this:

```
 foreach (array_keys($data) as $arrayKey) {
            var_dump($data[$arrayKey]);
        }
```

If I `var_dump` the `$data` array, the keys and values are visible in the console output (see below).
Please help, I'm going nuts trying to figure this one out. The array is read from a .csv file, encoding is reported as UTF-8 by IDE.

Thanks!

```
array(26) {
  ["code"]=>
  string(13) "xxxxxxxxx"
  ["category"]=>
  string(8) "ANVELOPE"
  ["category_url"]=>
  string(40) "https://edited"
  ["brand"]=>
  string(7) "edited"
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "AS1"
  ["price_reseller"]=>
  string(6) "190.87"
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "RON"
  ["stock"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "14-03-2022"
  ["url"]=>
  string(68) "https://edited"
  ["latime"]=>
  string(3) "165"
  ["diametru"]=>
  string(2) "15"
  ["talon"]=>
  string(2) "65"
  ["sezon"]=>
  string(4) "VARA"
  ["id_gr"]=>
  string(2) "81"
  ["id_vit"]=>
  string(1) "T"
  ["peco"]=>
  string(1) "E"
  ["ploaie"]=>
  string(1) "C"
  ["zgomot"]=>
  string(2) "71"
  ["image"]=>
  string(70) "https://edited"
  ["grupa"]=>
  string(6) "Turism"
  ["tehnologie_suplimentara"]=>
  string(2) "--"
  ["m_s"]=>
  string(2) "NU"
  ["Nr_unde"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["id_produs"]=>
  string(5) "edited"
  ["info_dot"]=>
  string(8) "DOT 2017"
}
```

Comment: I would look for small spelling errors, like "Code" instead of "code', or "$Data" instead of "$data", but there's nothing in your question I can do this with. That's why it is always important to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: _"For debugging purposes, I've tried to access them by doing this:"_ - So what was the outcome of that debugging? Please post the code (in it's proper context) that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ends up on this questiong, turns out the file I was reading contains ASCII characters, which were not printed in the console output.

I solved this by sanitizing with  `/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/` to remove those characters. The code snippet is available below.

The reporting as UTF8 was done by my PhpStorm.

```
$regex = <<<'END'
/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/
END;
preg_replace($regex, '$1', $stringToSanitize)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the key value of an array you have to use `$key` variable on your foreach as follow

```
foreach (array_keys($data) as $key => $arrayKey) {
```

to dump the keys of your object do the following code.

```
        foreach (array_keys($data) as $key => $item) {
            dump($key);                  // this will return the key value
            dump($item);                // this will return the value of the key
            dump($key . '--' . $item); // will return the key and value of your object
        }
```